# Redux + Typescript -> Error: A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined redux

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to import typescript in my redux application. I use redux toolkit createSlice function like this:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: sliceName,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateMode(state: SliceState, action: PayloadAction<ModePayload>) {
      state = action.payload.mode;
    },
  },
});
```

When I dispatch a updateMode action, I receive the following error:

```
Error: A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined
```

But my action.payload is well defined and redux toolkit is up to date. It have something to do with my code but I can't figure it out...

I tried to return state in updateMode and it works, but I get a TypeScript error:

```
Type '(state: SliceState, action: { payload: ModePayload; type: string; }) => SliceState' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<"SHOW_LIST", { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<"SHOW_LIST", PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>>'.
  Type '(state: SliceState, action: { payload: ModePayload; type: string; }) => SliceState' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<"SHOW_LIST", { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
    Type 'SliceState' is not assignable to type 'void | "SHOW_LIST"'.
      Type '"SHOW_SKILL"' is not assignable to type 'void | "SHOW_LIST"'
```

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong ?

Below my full code:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type SliceState = "SHOW_LIST" | "SHOW_SKILL";

let initialState: SliceState = "SHOW_LIST";

const sliceName = "mode";

interface ModePayload {
  mode: SliceState;
}

//--- Slice reducer ---

const modeSlice = createSlice({
  name: sliceName,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateMode(state: SliceState, action: PayloadAction<ModePayload>) {
      return (state = action.payload.mode);
    },
  },
});
export const { updateMode } = modeSlice.actions;
export default modeSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: My guess is you didn't understand very well how to define a slice and what is the state or `initialState` in this case.

Comment: Have you checked [this link?](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createslice); it seems `updateMode(...)` should be `updateMode: (...) => ...`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Yes I've tried both syntaxes with the same result.

Comment: @SecondSon Surely you might be right. That's why I've ask this question, I didn't find any answer in redux docs.

Comment: @EmmanuelMadarassou my point is if you understand what is a state, as [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) explains it then writing a slice might be less confusing as to what is a state and how to update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer and the creator of Redux Toolkit.

The actual problem is with this line:

```js
state = action.payload.mode;
```

This doesn't actually accomplish anything useful.  Immer works by tracking *mutations* to an existing value, like `state.someField = 123`.  The line you wrote only changes the local `state` variable to point to something else instead.

Immer requires that you either return an entirely new state value, *or* mutate the existing state.  That line of code does neither.  Instead, the reducer only ends up returning `undefined`, thus the error.

If you want to replace the existing state entirely, you should just do `return action.payload.mode`.

Also, as a side note: if `initialState` is correctly typed, you don't have to supply a type for `state` for each reducer, as it will be inferred.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I find this rather confusing cause the examples in the documentation do not return a value. Instead, they mutate the state locally. Is it that there is a mismatch between the documentation and redux toolkit?

Comment: No, the docs are correct. Immer lets you either 1) mutate the existing `state` value, or 2) create a new state value immutably yourself and return it (as if Immer wasn't involved): https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation .  However, _assigning_ `state = x` is not either of those - it's not a mutation, and it's not a return. FWIW, I do have a half-written "Writing Reducers with Immer" usage guide page that I need to finish writing and add to the RTK docs, which will cover these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Following the document, you might have to cast your type as following:

```js
const modeSlice = createSlice({
  name: sliceName,
  initialState: initialState as SliceState,
  reducers: {
    updateMode(state: SliceState, action: PayloadAction<ModePayload>) {
      return (state = action.payload.mode);
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would have something like this

```
type SliceState = {
  mode: string;
};

interface ModePayload {
  mode: string;
}

const initialState: SliceState = {
  mode: 'initial mode',
};

//--- Slice reducer ---

const modeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'modeSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateMode(state, action: PayloadAction<ModePayload>) {
      state.mode = action.payload.mode;
    },
  },
});

export const { actions, reducer, name: sliceKey } = modeSlice;
```

And then wherever you are importing this slice and you have to dispacth your action you will then have something like.

```js
import {actions} from '../mode-slice'

....

// somewhere in your component/view or whatever

dispatch(actions.updateMode({mode: 'new mode'}))
```

Essentially your slice holds a slice of your global state stored by redux and you are slicing down and manipulating just a slice of it. The slice contains both the reducer(s) and the action(s) that allow you to manipulate your state(slice of the state).

React Boilerplate CRA has some good explanations about it right [here](https://cansahin.gitbook.io/react-boilerplate-cra-template/).

Comment: This solution will give me a state like {mode: {mode: 'Initial mode'}} but wouldn't it be easier to juste have a state like {mode:'initial mode'} ?
That's what I've done before without typescript because I haven't decide yet if I need more information in mode slice.

Comment: It’s a slice... you have slices for your state... those states slices are the ones you can change to make your one global state. Please read the docs carefully or adapt this solution to your problem as you see fit.

Comment: Yes I know that It's not my global state. In my application I have slice for mode, skill, selections, etc. I just provide the code for my mode slice because the problem only concerned this part. And I've seen this use of slice in other application and it suited well my needs. Thanks for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers.

I merged both your answers and I get the following result wich does what I wanted:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type SliceState = "SHOW_LIST" | "SHOW_SKILL";

let initialState: SliceState = "SHOW_LIST";

const sliceName = "mode";

interface ModePayload {
  mode: SliceState;
}

//--- Slice reducer ---

const modeSlice = createSlice({
  name: sliceName,
  initialState: initialState as SliceState,
  reducers: {
    updateMode(state, action: PayloadAction<ModePayload>) {
      return action.payload.mode;
    },
  },
});
export const { updateMode } = modeSlice.actions;
export default modeSlice.reducer;
```

This allows me to have my mode slice in my global state equal "SHOW_LIST" || "SHOW_SKILL" which is what I wanted in the first place. If I need more data for my mode, I will surely make my slice state like this:

```
{
  mode: "SHOW_LIST",
  otherAttribute: otherValue,
  ...,
}
```